# Automatic LDR switching circuit

Tags: mosfet, low-power, esp32, ldr

I would like to create an energy efficient LDR evaluation circuit. The circuit should provide the possibility to connect an external LDR (R8) or use an internal, permanently installed LDR (R25). When an external LDR (R8) is connected via a wire, the external LDR should be used, otherwise the internal one (R25) should be used.

Here is what I came up with:

[image: internal and external LDR switching circuit]

I will have a 4-pin connector (J8) to which the external LDR (R8) connects. There is also a jumper installed, which will pull Q6 Gate HIGH and thus disconnect R25.

At the same time R8 will be connected and read by the `ldr_val` pin using the voltage divider (R26).

Note that the circuit will only be powered by `ldr_en` when the LDR should be read by `ldr_val` to save the current flowing through the voltage divider.

Can this solution work on my PCB? Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: Your connector is your business. But there are physical connectors that will make/break connections when a plug is inserted. That would be electronically simpler. But it may be mechanically or cost unacceptable.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the FET at all:

If you remove Q6 and R24, then connect the internal LDR to pin 2.
Now when the jumper is in place you measure the internal LDR.  When the jumper is removed you measure the external LDR.

In neither the OP circuit or modified as I've described can you measure the external LDR if the jumper is in place; unless I'm missing something.

Comment: You'd have to use a blanking (internal, 3,2) plug and an external (only the the external LDR connection on 4,1) to make this viable.

Comment: @JackCreasey Correct, as stated "When the jumper is in place..."  The jumper is between pins 2 & 3 on the connector.